# How to use a generic type parameter in a Javadoc link?

Tags: generics, javadoc

I have the following code:

```
/**
 * [...]
 *
 * @see #setShowOn(T, Device)
 */
 public static <T extends HasStyle> void setHideOn(T widget, Device device) {
     [...]
 }
```

`setShowOn` has the same signature as `setHideOn`. Javadoc complains:

```
Tag @see: can't find setHideOn(T, Device) in com.github.[...]
```

I tried different alternatives (`@see #setShowOn(<T>, Device)`, `@see #setShowOn(T extends HasStyle, Device)`, ...) but those didn't even work in Eclipse. (`@see #setShowOn(T, Device)` does.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer. This works:

```
@see #setHideOn(HasStyle, Device)
```

Comment: That would make sense -- the erasure of T in your example would have to be HasStyle. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

I've had to resort to the erasure of the method that has generic parameters, e.g.:

```
@see #setHideOn(Object, Device)
```

In [JOpt Simple](http://pholser.github.com/jopt-simple) I have an example of this -- in OptionSet.java, there are `@linkplain` references to `ArgumentAcceptingOptionSpec#defaultsTo(V, V...)` that I have to encode as `ArgumentAcceptingOptionSpec#defaultsTo(Object, Object[])` instead.

Comment: Strange. I see it working in your docs but I get the same error message as before.